# Indicate that function type checks in mypy

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a factory function that takes a number of `Optional` arguments and creates objects depending on which of the arguments are `None` and which aren't. I also have a function that checks whether all of its arguments are `None`, and a function that checks whether all of its arguments are not `None`. I use these to do checking. Here's the MWE:

```
from typing import Optional

class Arg1:
    def __init__(self, arg1: float):
        pass

class Arg1And2:
    def __init__(self, arg1: float, arg2: float):
        pass

class Arg2And3:
    def __init__(self, arg2: float, arg3: float):
        pass

def _all_none(*args) -> bool:
    return all(a is None for a in args)

def _none_none(*args) -> bool:
    return all(a is not None for a in args)

def dispatch_factory(
    arg1: Optional[float] = None,
    arg2: Optional[float] = None,
    arg3: Optional[float] = None
):
    if _all_none(arg2, arg3) and _none_none(arg1):
        return Arg1(arg1)  # <-- This throws a mypy error
    elif _all_none(arg3) and _none_none(arg1, arg2):
        return Arg1And2(arg1, arg2)  # <-- And this
    elif _all_none(arg1) and _none_none(arg2, arg3):
        return Arg2And3(arg2, arg3)  # <-- And this
    else:
        raise ValueError("Combination of arguments invalid")
```

Of course, we know that my construction of `Arg1` is valid because we just checked that `arg1` isn't `None`, and therefore must be `float`. We know the same things for `Arg1And2` and `Arg2And3`. I understand why mypy does this - it can't actually *know* that `arg1` isn't `None`, since there could be all sorts of tomfoolery happening in `_none_none` - but is there any way for me to tell mypy that `_none_none` guarantees types about its arguments, without explicitly adding `cast(float, arg1)` inside the `dispatch_factory` function?

(Also, if anyone has a convincing alternative to this methodology that avoids this problem or is cleaner, I'm happy to hear it.)

Comment: Did you mean ``def __init__(self, arg1: float):`` instead of ``def __init__(arg1: float):`` (same for the others)?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Wrote that off the top of my head in SO itself, I'll add them in now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifying types in a branch is known as Type Guard. This is not possible currently, but proposed in [PEP 647 -- User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0647/).

```py
from typing import TypeGuard, Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def all_none(args: list[Optional[T]]) -> TypeGuard[List[None]]:
    return all(a is None for a in args)
```

---

Since the code explicitly has to pass each argument to the guard, it is roughly the same effort to unroll the check – which works for current type checking.

```py
def dispatch_factory(
    arg1: Optional[float] = None,
    arg2: Optional[float] = None,
    arg3: Optional[float] = None
):
    if arg1 is not None and arg2 is None and arg3 is None:
        return Arg1(arg1)
    elif arg1 is not None and arg2 is not None and arg3 is None:
        return Arg1And2(arg1, arg2)
    elif arg1 is None and arg2 is not None and arg3 is not None:
        return Arg2And3(arg2, arg3)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Combination of arguments invalid")
```

Oftentimes, a type guard can be reformulated to *return* the values if they are of the proper type or nothing otherwise. This allows to use the guard in an `if` statement/expression (to only proceed if anything is returned) together with an assignment expression (to store the validated values).

```py
def _all_none(*args: Optional[T]) -> List[None]:
    if all(a is None for a in args):  # MyPy does not understand this to narrow `args`, so we need the next ignore
        return list(args)  # type: ignore
    return []

def _none_none(*args: Optional[T]) -> List[T]:
    if all(a is not None for a in args):
        return list(args)  # type: ignore
    return []

def dispatch_factory(
    arg1: Optional[float] = None,
    arg2: Optional[float] = None,
    arg3: Optional[float] = None
):
    if _all_none(arg2, arg3) and (args :=_none_none(arg1)):
        return Arg1(*args)
    elif _all_none(arg3) and (args := _none_none(arg1, arg2)):
        return Arg1And2(*args)
    elif _all_none(arg1) and (args := _none_none(arg1, arg2)):
        return Arg2And3(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Combination of arguments invalid")
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I think I'll definitely be using the return-style reformulation, that's exactly the kind of clean solution I was looking for

Comment: Quick follow-up question: you annotate the `_all_none` and `_none_none` functions with `TypeVar`, but I would imagine that suggests that they accept and return lists of a single type. Shouldn't the annotation be `Optional[Any]` and `List[Any]`?

Comment: The ``TypeVar`` can always be filled in by a Union or baseclass. If need be, you can ``@overload`` them for some fixed arity (e.g. ``(Optional[T1]) -> T1``, ``(Optional[T1], Optional[T2]) -> Tuple[T1, T2]`` and so on) as you see realistic; usually, 4-6 parameters are sufficient for realistic use.